# What are specific confitions where Tag 91 is mandatory in EMV response data?

Tags: emv

I am new to EMV development. My question is regarding `Tag 91 (Issuer Authetication Data)` which is sent by Issuer in `EMV response`. In my case, when tag 91 is missing in response packet then chip card decides to decline the transaction even if issuer has approved transaction online. So I am wondering whether `Tag 91` is a mandatory tag which needs to be sent by issuer each time it approves a transaction online and what is industry wide understanding about it. Please let me know thoughts on it.

Also, In my case, `Application Interchange Profile Byte 1, Bit 3 = 1` which means external authentication is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you working for Card Application or Terminal Application ?

Issuer authentication always have to be performed unless you are doing a partial chip implementation. I am sure you know that it is an additional level of security that ensures that the response came from the correct issuer.
When AIP B1B3 is on, it means card will expect tag 91.

In some cases it is even default. eg. D-PAS( Diners/Discover) AIP B1B3 is off, since it does not support External Authenticate. It is verified during second Gen AC. In such cases if the issuer wants card to not decline the transaction when ARPC not present, in the ACO( Application configuration Option), it is explicitly mentioned about partial chip implementation.

Check each payment scheme card and terminal specifications manual careful before you implement, as any loop holes in implementation may help a fraudster skip the security you wish to provide.Thumb rule, if you get ARPC from issuer, always sent it to card. Let the card decide.

Comment: Thanks! I only wanted to confirm that when AIP B1B3 is on then does Tag 91 is mandatory to be sent by Issuer - and as you replied , it is expected else card may decline transaction even if it was approved online by Issuer.

Comment: Yes. when in the AIP it is set as 1, it means that the issuer is capable of sending the tag back to card in response message. At the same the bit is off always does not mean that tag 91 is not expected( case of D-PAS).

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks mate. you did not mention what you kind of application you are working on :)

Comment: Actually it's a Card payment application which is installed on POS. It is now being upgraded for EMV standard.

Answer (score 1):

From Card Application side I can add that "Application Interchange Profile Byte 1, Bit 3 = 1 means external authentication is supported, but not required. What does it mean ? Card may support Issuer Authentication, but may not required it for online transaction (issuer authentication can be mandatory or optional in card internal parameters). I.e. for optional it would be great to do auth, but if not - no problem, do online. And if Issuer have not sent tag 91 card may aprove transaction.

Comment: But in my case, Card is always declining transaction if host doesn't send Tag 91. You are correct that AIP B1B3 means that external auth is supported and not mandatory. May be we need to contact terminal vendors e.g. Verifone or Equinox to avoid decline by card if Tag 91 is not present in response from Issuer. Or it may also be broken collis test or issuer side settings problem. But thanks for your reply!

Comment: Card will decline transation if IA(issuer authentication) mandatory or terminal asks for AC in GenerateAc2. Or for very different another reasons. Actually i don't clear understand which the layer(teminal, card, host) you explore.